# DataFrame explode running slow

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a Python dataframe that I am trying to use explode on a column "transactions_details" that contains array of elements. It takes very long to return data. Is there an alternate for 'explode'. Not sure even if explode is the right command.

My current output:

```
userId  username    transactions
44782   eyuan       object
                    details: [{"expiration": "2022-09-08T00:00:00", "externalItemId": null, "from_sitelocationId": 1821, "itemDescription": "Avastin 2.5MG PINE SILICONE FREE", "itemId": 50679, "lot": "59529", "ndcCode": "50242-0060-01", "ndcCode10Digit": "50242-060-01", "ndcDesc": "Avastin 2.5MG PINE SILICONE FREE", "qty": 1, "to_sitelocationId": 0},{"expiration": "2022-09-08T00:00:00", "externalItemId": null, "from_sitelocationId": 1821, "itemDescription": "Avastin 2.5MG PINE SILICONE FREE", "itemId": 50679, "lot": "59530", "ndcCode": "50243-0060-01", "ndcCode10Digit": "50243-060-01", "ndcDesc": "Avastin 2.5MG PINE SILICONE FREE", "qty": 1, "to_sitelocationId": 0}]
                    modifiedByUsername: null
                    transactionType: 6
                    transactionTypeName: "Use"
```

My desired output:

```
userid        username   expiration           externalItemId  from_sitelocationId       itemDescription            itemId   lot    ndcCode        ndcCode10Digit    ndcDesc                           qty  to_sitelocationId   
44782         eyuan        2022-09-08T00:00:00       null            1821               Avastin 2.5MG PINE SILICONE  50679    59529  50242-0060-01   50242-060-01     Avastin 2.5MG PINE SILICONE FREE   1    0       
44782         eyuan        2022-09-08T00:00:00       null            1821               Avastin 2.5MG PINE SILICONE  50679    59530  50243-0060-01   50243-060-01     Avastin 2.5MG PINE SILICONE FREE   1    0
```

Here is my code:

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("transactions_details.itemid", explode(col("transactions.details.itemid")))\
.withColumn("transactions_details.expiration", explode(col("transactions.details.expiration")))\
.withColumn("transactions_details.externalitemid", explode(col("transactions.details.externalitemid")))\
.withColumn("transactions_details.from_sitelocationid", explode(col("transactions.details.from_sitelocationid")))\
.withColumn("transactions_details.itemDescription", explode(col("transactions.details.itemDescription")))\
.withColumn("transactions_details.lot", explode(col("transactions.details.lot")))\
.withColumn("transactions_details.ndcCode", explode(col("transactions.details.ndcCode")))\
.withColumn("transactions_details.ndcCode10Digit", explode(col("transactions.details.ndcCode10Digit")))\
.withColumn("transactions_details.ndcDesc", explode(col("transactions.details.ndcDesc")))\
.withColumn("transactions_details.qty", explode(col("transactions.details.qty")))\
.withColumn("transactions_details.to_sitelocationid", explode(col("transactions.details.to_sitelocationid")))\
.drop("transactions")
display(df2)
```

Also, there can certain usernames that can have multiple transactions

Comment: Could you share what the desired output is?

Comment: Input and desired output are posted.

Comment: Would the `json_normalize` function work? You can read about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

Comment: I tried, `result = pd.json_normalize(df1)`. Getting "'Column' object is not callable" error. Can you please suggest.